# MVC: which MVC layer is correct for this method?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a method that build a Child Object list for each parent Object.Here is my code:

```
class Element{
    function getChilList($child){
      Element parentDataObject[];
      if(count($this->parentDataObject)>0)              
            foreach ($this->parentDataObject as $c){    
               $this->parentDataObject[] =  $c;
               $this->TryAddAsSubProject($c);
            }
    }
}
```

based on that list, i have to display all parent with their child in the View
But i was confused that, on which Layer of MVC (Model/View/Controller) to put this code so the parent View Layer can easily get all Child List.And another thing is that if i need a List child of  in each parent class of same type, then is it violating the property of MVC pattern? that is please suggest correct one.Thanks

Comment: It's unclear to me what this code is supposed to do. But generally: is it specific to something related to *presentation* (output)? Then it's the View. Otherwise, is it a core part of your app, regardless of what presentation (output) is used or where input comes from? Then it's probably part of the Model. Or is it related to handling input (web request)? Then it would be Controller.

Comment: Thank you @deceze for the reply. data will be read from some file & that list will be generate. after that to display that List on HTML view. This is the case.

Answer (score 1):

This class should reside in a the business layer. Another option is putting this code in a Data Access Layer (DAL) and then call it from the business layer to get the data and do further processing if necessary. Eventually the business layer code will be called from the controller.